# How to change approver for the request in OIM?

Tags: identity, identity-management, oim, identitymanager

I need to update the approver user for some request in OIM? What is the best practices/solutions or APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to

http://hostname:port_number/integration/worklistapp
hostname is the name of the host computer on which Oracle SOA Suite is installed

The port_number used at installation

Enter the user name and password.

You can use the preseeded user to log in as an administrator. If you have loaded the demo user community in the identity store, then you can use other users such as jstein or jcooper.

The user name and password must exist in the user community provided to JAZN. See Oracle Fusion Middleware Administrator's Guide for Oracle SOA Suite and Oracle Business Process Management Suite for the organizational hierarchy of the demo user community used in examples throughout this chapter.

Click Login.

Go to administrative task, search for the request, select the request and from left drop down select reassign. Provide the userID to whom request needs to be routed to. and click on OK.